Postman and Tv4 not validate internal array objects (question)
I am playing with the petstore api examples and I am trying to validate array of objects using postman and tv4.
Edit: After @Wladimir Diskowski put me in the right way,All schema.definitions must be loaded into tv4 before any validation to ensure all internal object references will be found.
To reproduce:
1. Previous Request to fetch petStore Swagger file and load on environment:
GET->https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json 
Test Tab execution:
const jsonResponse = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json", jsonResponse);

2.Make new postman Request
GET https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available
Test Tab:
//1.Get Response
const jsonResponse = pm.response.json();

//2. Load From Previos calls 
var _schema = pm.environment.get("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json");
for (var prop in _schema.definitions) {
    tv4.addSchema('#/definitions/'+prop, _schema["definitions"][prop]);
}

//3. Look for my API Operation schemas

const findByStatusSuccessSchema = _schema["paths"]["/pet/findByStatus"].get.responses[200].schema;
var isValid = tv4.validate(jsonResponse.slice(1, 10), findByStatusSuccessSchema); // slice because not all array elements in response are valid
console.log("1.isValid " +isValid); //true

//4.Try with not valid Pet objects Array

var notValidPetArray = [{"propA":"valueA"}]
isValid = tv4.validate(notValidPetArray, findByStatusSuccessSchema);
console.log("2.isValid " + isValid);  //false
console.log("error " + tv4.error); // 'name' is missing


//5. Simpl malformmed Pet  (internal tag.id property must be a int)

var malfommedPet = {
        "id": 9223372036854761039,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "string"
        },
        "name": "doggie",
        "photoUrls": [
            "string"
        ],
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": "I must be a number",
                "name": "string"
            }
        ],
        "status": "available"
    };

var petSchema = _schema["definitions"]["Pet"];
var malfommedPet_isValid = tv4.validate(malfommedPet, petSchema);
console.log("Malformed Pet isValid=  "+ malfommedPet_isValid);
console.log("error " + tv4.error); // Invalid type: string (expected integer) (tags.id must be a int)

Now I am able to validate path request response against schema defined at paths/{pathID}/responses/{response}/schema.

I played with your example and this is my result:
...

//3. Look for my APIOperation schemas
const findByStatusSuccessSchema = _schema["paths"]["/pet/findByStatus"].get.responses[200].schema;
console.log('loaded schema: ' + JSON.stringify( findByStatusSuccessSchema));
const petSchema = _schema["definitions"]["Pet"];
tv4.addSchema('#/definitions/Pet', petSchema);
var isValid = tv4.validate(jsonResponse.slice(1, 10), findByStatusSuccessSchema); // slice because not all array elements in response are valid
console.log("1.isValid " +isValid); //true

//4.Try with not valid Pet objects Array
var notValidPetArray = [{"propA":"valueA"}]
isValid = tv4.validate(notValidPetArray, findByStatusSuccessSchema);
console.log("2.isValid " + isValid);  //false
console.log("error " + tv4.error); // 'name' is missing


Hi Wladimir, thank so much, adding PetSchemas as (#/definitions/Pet) works!. But I found that I have to manually add all schemas because the internal Pet object references (as Tags, Category) need to be added too. I dont kwon if tv4 can load all definition schemas at once . But anyway you response put me in the right way. Thanks !so much!!
